# Getting ClientError: ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: file name not defined

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to write a python script for uploading csv files into graphdb with apoc procedure call. I am trying to make it dynamic. So I have a function name CreateNodes(filename, label) which takes  a csvfile and node label for creating NODE in graphdb for given query

My code is given below

```
def CreateNodes(filename,label):
    print(filename,label)
    print(type(filename),type(label))
    nodequery="""CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.csv(filename) yield map as row return row','CREATE (p:label) SET p = row', {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true})"""
    return nodequery


query=CreateNodes("test.csv","NODE1")
```

I have checked my function and filename and label parameter takes the passing value

```
query=CreateNodes("test.csv","NODE1")
test.csv NODE1
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
```

but when I am going to run graphdriver.run(query) for creating  node in graphdb

```
graphdriver.run(query)
```

I  am getting below error

> ClientError: ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure 'apoc.periodic.iterate': Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.v3_5.util.SyntaxException: Variable 'filename' not defined (line 1, column 43 (offset: 42))

maybe I  am missing something in query. In fact  I have also tried explicit filename.csv in my apoc query then it worked. but I want to  pass  the filename and label variable inside cypher query for getting result

I am using py2neo python driver for neo4j, and my neo4j version is 3.5.6 and my apoc procedure library version is 3.5.0.4

Comment: Any update on this one please ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using parameters. The [run() function](https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.run) takes an optional second parameter dictionary of parameters you want the query to use.

Also, in the query itself, you need to prefix the parameter name with `$`, so proper usage would be:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv($filename) ...
```

Where `filename` is the key of the parameter in the dictionary of parameters in your run() call.